# GLSL 330 core not supported

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, sdl

so I'm basically a beginner in OpenGL and I was trying to create my own shaders to form a simple triangle. In doing that I used SDL to create the window (as you can see in the screenshot attached that its being successfully loaded) even though the tutorial made use of glfw3 and glad (I had to resort to SDL because I was unable to effectively include the latter libraries). It keeps giving me the following error

"GLSL is not supported. Supported version are: 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, ... 3.20 ES"

Is the SDL the cause of the problem?

Operating system: Ubuntu 18.04;
 IDE: CodeBlocks;

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include "display.h"

using namespace std;
const char *vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
        "gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x,aPos.y,aPos.z,1.0f)\n"
    "}\0";
const char *fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
    "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
        "FragColor = vec4(1.0f,0.5f,0.2f,1.0f);\n"
    "}\0";
int main()
{
    Display display(800,600,"Moiz");
    while(!display.isClosed())
    {
        glClearColor(0.0f,0.15f,0.3f,1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        display.Update();
        int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1 , &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vertexShader);
        int success;
        char infoLog[512];
        glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
        }
        int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource,NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
        glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
        if (!success)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Display.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include "display.h"

using namespace std;

Display::Display(int width, int height,const string &title)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);


    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE, 32);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

    m_window = SDL_CreateWindow(title.c_str(),SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,width,height,SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    m_glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(m_window);
    GLenum status = glewInit();
    if(status != GLEW_OK)
    {
        std::cerr << "GLEW FAILED TO INITIALIZE" << endl;
    }
}
bool Display::isClosed(){
    return m_isClosed;
}
void Display::Update()
{
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(m_window);
    SDL_Event e;
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&e))
    {
        if(e.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            m_isClosed = true;
        }
    }
}

Display::~Display()
{
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(m_glContext);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(m_window);
    SDL_Quit();
}

Display::Display(const Display& other)
{
    //copy ctor
}

Display& Display::operator=(const Display& rhs)
{
    if (this == &rhs) return *this; // handle self assignment
    //assignment operator
    return *this;
}
```

:Error Image

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWgtG.png)

Comment: Find your graphics driver specs.  That would help.

Comment: `Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, ... 3.20 ES` Try one of these.

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].  No way of telling what sins "`Display`" may be committing.  For all we know it might not be requesting a Core context at all.

Comment: I don't see you early call `SDL_Init` nor the parameters you use to ask for a GL 3.3 core context.

Comment: I included the display.cpp @genpfault

Comment: @Axalo I tried adding 3.20 ES it gave me a syntax error. I replaced it with #version 320 ES core.

Comment: @Ripi2 I added the display.cpp for reference there I have passed SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING). And umm? I how do request a Core context?

Comment: See this [wiki example](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tutorial1:_Creating_a_Cross_Platform_OpenGL_3.2_Context_in_SDL_(C_/_SDL)) about creating a *Core Profile* context with SDL

Comment: @Axalo It's AMD Radeon (TM) R5 M330 2GB.

Comment: @Ripi2 Oh okay.. I'll look it up

Comment: Hey, I used the extension viewer it tends to support OPENGL 4.4.  So should I create a context as 440?

Comment: @Ripi2 it worked thanks man. And thank you all for your super fast replies..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You're missing a semicolon after the `vec4` in your vertex shader
- If you're using Mesa be aware (historically; this has been changing for some drivers in the past few weeks/months) it only hands out GL contexts >3.0 if you request a Core context.  You can use `SDL_GL_SetAttribute()` to make `SDL_CreateWindow()` request one:

  ```
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3 );
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3 );
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE );
  ```

All together (this is what I meant by [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): a single file, depending only on well-known libraries like SDL/GLEW/GLM/GLFW):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Display
{
public:
    Display( int width, int height, const std::string &title )
        : m_isClosed( false )
    {
        SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );

        SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8 );
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8 );
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8 );
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8 );
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE, 32 );
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1 );

        SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3 );
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3 );
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE );

        m_window = SDL_CreateWindow
            (
            title.c_str(), SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
            width, height,
            SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL
            );
        m_glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext( m_window );
        GLenum status = glewInit();
        if( status != GLEW_OK )
        {
            std::cerr << "GLEW FAILED TO INITIALIZE" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    bool isClosed()
    {
        return m_isClosed;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow( m_window );
        SDL_Event e;
        while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) )
        {
            if( e.type == SDL_QUIT )
            {
                m_isClosed = true;
            }
        }
    }

    ~Display()
    {
        SDL_GL_DeleteContext( m_glContext );
        SDL_DestroyWindow( m_window );
        SDL_Quit();
    }

    Display( const Display& other )
    {
        //copy ctor
    }

    Display& operator=( const Display& rhs )
    {
        if( this == &rhs ) return *this; // handle self assignment
        //assignment operator
        return *this;
    }

private:
    SDL_Window* m_window;
    SDL_GLContext m_glContext;
    bool m_isClosed;
};

const char *vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x,aPos.y,aPos.z,1.0f);\n"
"}\0";
const char *fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 FragColor;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"FragColor = vec4(1.0f,0.5f,0.2f,1.0f);\n"
"}\0";

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    Display display( 800, 600, "Moiz" );
    while( !display.isClosed() )
    {
        glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.15f, 0.3f, 1.0f );
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
        display.Update();
        int vertexShader = glCreateShader( GL_VERTEX_SHADER );
        glShaderSource( vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL );
        glCompileShader( vertexShader );
        int success;
        char infoLog[ 512 ];
        glGetShaderiv( vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success );
        if( !success )
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog( vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog );
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
        }
        int fragmentShader = glCreateShader( GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER );
        glShaderSource( fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL );
        glCompileShader( fragmentShader );
        glGetShaderiv( fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success );
        if( !success )
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog( fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog );
            std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, make sure to check that `SDL_CreateWindow()` and `SDL_GL_CreateContext()` return valid values.

Comment: Oh it worked. Thanks man. Listen what does this line do    SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE );

Comment: @MoizSohail: See the [`SDL_GL_SetAttribute()` wiki docs](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GL_SetAttribute).  That sets a bit inside SDL that makes the next `SDL_CreateWindow()` call request a [Core GL context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context#OpenGL_3.2_and_Profiles) via the system-appropriate [`ARB_create_context`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/GLX_ARB_create_context.txt) extension from the OS when it creates the window.